# date parsing in java

Tags: java, sql, date

I have written following program to convert date string to sql date object to store in db2 but the ouput shown is  2013-01-02 instead of 2013-02-02. can anyone explain why??

```
String string = "02/02/2013";
Date date = null;

try {
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
    java.sql.Date newDate=new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
    System.out.println(newDate);

} catch (ParseException e) {                    
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: please tell if there is any other way to do this thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For month you should use `MM` instead of `mm`. `mm` is used for `minutes in hour`: -

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Answer (score 1):

your format should be

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

note that `mm` is for **minutes** whereas `MM` is for **Month**

[**Check the Doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)